# MongoDB unique users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a login page where users can add favourite food item, but I'm not sure how exactly I would make it so that it knows exactly which user is logged in. I want to ultimately be able to edit add things so each specific user has its own unique list of favourite items. I've tried looking everywhere, but I can't seem to find any information. I am looking for advice on a general direction such as specific packages etc.

Comment: You will need something like `session` to know which user is sending the request to the server. You can read more from this tutorial: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/session-management-in-nodejs-using-expressjs-and-express-session/. The keyword to search is `session` and `cookie`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't use a mongoDB database so I'm not sure if the same thing would apply?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly - you want to create a page that is only accessible by users who are logged in, and you want to use the unique id of that user so that you can determine a list of favourite items for the user?

The way that you can do this is by creating models for the data that you're looking to store - one for the user and one for favorite items. Your models would probably look something like this:

```
user: {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
}
```

and the favourite items would be

```
itemsArray: [
  {
    itemName: string
  }
]
```

Mongoose is the package that you will want to use for modeling. You can read more about it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html. (the package is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose).

Also note that in MongoDB, all documents are given a unique id automatically. You don't need to include them in the model. So your user would really look more like this in the database, once they've been entered:

```
user: {
  _id: 507f191e810c19729de860ea,
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi yes, I have that right now(the second block of text)!!! I am already using mongoose and I use express and node too. But lets say I have 3 users each with the format of the code in your second block in my database. . I'm struggling to understand how to make it so that when I login it knows that it goes to user1 vs user2 and then when i update the favorite food of the user, it knows which user to go to (both on backend and front end). All I have right now is that when I enter the correct details and it exists in database, it will just redirect my page. But not sure how to make it unique.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes I understand what you mean. You might want to read this article which describes ways that data can be stored in mongoDB (but really any noSQL database). In my opinion it's a lot easier and makes more sense to put the itemsArray into the user. This way it's really quick and easy to query the favorite items of the user. You can embed the itemsArray like this into the user model:

    user: {
     firstName: string,
     lastName: string,
     itemsArray: [
  {
    itemName: string
  }
]
    }

Comment: In order to query the right user, you would just get the user id when they log in and use that id to query the user model in mongoDB. Since you can put the favorite items array right onto the user this makes the query very easy to do.

Here are two links that you might want to check out: 
Relationships in MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Embedded vs Referenced documents:
https://betterprogramming.pub/embedded-vs-referenced-documents-in-mongodb-how-to-choose-correctly-for-increased-performance-d267769b8671

Comment: @JackZ Does this help you? If not, what are you stuck on?

Comment: Hi Robert, Sorry I did not see this in my notifications. I will take a look at your comment and then ask if I have any follow up questions. I've been working on something else lately. Thank you so much for following up!!